# Use of unassigned local variable 'month'

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I am getting this error after using catch-try in my code. When I hadn’t used the try-catch in my code then editor would not give this error, but when I closed my program in try-catch code then it started giving this error.  My code is given bellow.

```
try
{
     month = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
catch (FormatException ee) 
{
     Console.WriteLine(ee.Message);
}
if (month > 12 || mnth < 0)
{
     Console.Write("----Incorrect Month...plz Re-");
     lp_val = 1;
}
```

Comment: replace month with mnth as the error suggests.

Comment: Are `month` and `mnth` variables different? Or you just missed typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem :** you declared a variable `mnth` but didnot intialize it.so if the user input is not a valid integre as input Parse function throws exception and variable mnth still is not initialized.

**Solution :** initialize variable `mnth` at the time of declaration.

Try This:

```
try
{
    mnth=0;
    mnth = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
catch (FormatException ee) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(ee.Message);
}
if (mnth > 12 || mnth < 0)
{
    Console.Write("----Incorrect Month...plz Re-");
    lp_val = 1;
}
```

OR

You can move your if block inside the try block.

```
try
{
    mnth=0;
    mnth = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (mnth > 12 || mnth < 0)
    {
        Console.Write("----Incorrect Month...plz Re-");
        lp_val = 1;
    }
}
catch (FormatException ee) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(ee.Message);
}
```

Comment: @PirFahimShah: You are welcome :) , I'm glad tobe help of you.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you have two variables, `month`, and `mnth`. It looks like this is just wan error when created by posting the question here, but if it is not, make sure you resolve any typos in your code.

If an exception is raised by `Int32.Parse` the result will never be assigned to `month`, so it's not guaranteed to be assigned when you're evaluating the condition later.

The solution is to initialize the variable outside the the `try` block:

```
int month = 0;
```

Or to use [`Int32.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of wrapping it in a `try`/`catch`:

```
int month;
if (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out month)) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unable to parse input");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that you have variables named month and mnth, if the try-block code throws an exception, the line is not executed and mnth is not initialized to any value.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you declare `month` variable but you didn't initialize it.

This code gives the same error with your code;

```
int month;
if(month < 12)
{
   //
}
```

That's why you should initialize it before you use it. For example use;

```
int month = 0;
```

instead

```
int month;
```